# Why Vo =Vo1-Vo2?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

In above triple op amp circuit Vo is found as

[image]

I know it is difference amplifier and since R1 and R2 is on the both side of op amp Vo=(R2/R1)*(Vo2-Vo1)

Comment: Thank you for your correction. it was typos

Comment: What do you know about the resistor values?

Comment: They are unknown.

Comment: Yes, you are right is should be Vo = Vo2 - Vo1. We can apply superposition and you will see why. $$ Vo = -V_{o1}\frac{R_2}{R_1} + V_{o2} *(1+\frac{R_2}{R1})*\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}=- V_{o1}\frac{R_2}{R_1}+V_{o2}\frac{R_2}{R_1} = (V_{o2} - V_{o1})\frac{R_2}{R_1}  $$

Comment: The overall gain or s21=(R3/Rg+1)*R2/R1 and the input impedance s11 is very high and balanced.  The CMRR thus is limited by imbalance on the sources and twisted pairs to stray noise.

Comment: In some reference, they mentioned that the Vo= (Vo2−Vo1). So that why I got confused